# Creating a class which has the internal modifier

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test some code which utilises a library which has a dependency hidden internally via the 'internal' class modifier.

During the setup of the tests I would like to be able to create an instance of the internal  class. Normally I would try something like:

```
var type = typeof (FooBar);
var parameterlessCtor = (from c in type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        where c.GetParameters().Length == 0 select c).FirstOrDefault();

object instance;
if(parameterlessCtor != null)
{
    instance = parameterlessCtor.Invoke(null);
}
```

The obvious problem with this is 'typeof(FooBar)' - I can't do typeof on an internal type.

Any ideas if I can get round this anyway?

Oh and I can't rebuild the assembly with internally visible attribute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No but you can retrieve the type from its full name using [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

```
var type = Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.Foobar, YourNameSpace, Version=x.Y.Z.K, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz");
```

Comment: Please add how he would create the instance, and I'll upvote.

Comment: I meant give an example of how he would create an instance of this type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do this.

```
        Type type = typeof (Class1).Assembly.GetType("Class2");
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Where Class1 is a public class in the same assembly as your internal type and Class2 is your internal type.

Not the nicest solution and you are going to have to use reflection to invoke the methods as you cant cast, but it works